# Disabling touchscreen to extend battery life?

Tags: power-management, battery, touchscreen

I've read various posts about extending battery life of laptops and notebooks. And I've done various of things to extend it. But I'm wondering does touchscreen take power and how much? Would it be good idea to disable touchscreen and is it even possible?

I'm using lenovo ideapad s210 touch. And I don't need touchscreen at all.

edit: sorry forgot to say that I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64bt.

.silouan

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 1):

To extend the battery life greatly do the following:

TLP helps laptop reduce the ammount of power consumed in a much more efficient way than any other:

First: Uninstall laptop mode tools

```
sudo apt-get remove laptop-mode-tools
```

Then install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

Finally start it:

```
sudo tlp start
```

You will gain about 1 hour more battery life approx.

PS: You can always update to 13.10 that has the latest kernel available and have a better power management kernel updated for machines like yours.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 0):

The sensors which track touchscreen presses, and the CPU time used to interpret that, use a very, very small amount of power, and I would look elsewhere for improved battery runtime.